# If $x=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000000}}$, what is the value of $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$?

Tags: radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, telescopic-series

If $x=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1000000}}$, what is the value of $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$?

I'm sure I'm supposed to use telescoping series to solve this problem, but I don't know how to start. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: @MartinR How the hell did you find that. Holy cow.

Comment: @DonThousand: Easy with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%3D1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B2%7D%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B3%7D%7D%2B…%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1000000%7D%7D%24&p=19)

Comment: Whoaaaa, that's news to me.

Comment: See for example [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27325/429699) to “How do you search for duplicates?” on Meta.